# Binary Search Algorithm with interval

Tags: python, algorithm, search, binary

I am trying to change my code so instead of finding a specific value of the array it will output the value of an interval if found, example being 60-70. Any help is appreciated.

```
def binary (array, value):

    while len(array)!= 0:
        mid = len(array) // 2

        if value == array[mid]:           
            return value
        elif value > array[mid]:       
            array = array[mid+1:]
        elif value < array [mid]:          
            array = array[0:mid]

sequence = [1,2,5,9,13,42,69,123,256]

print( "found", binary(sequence,70) )
```

I have this so far and want it to find an specified interval, so if i specify 60-70 it will find what is in between.

Comment: What does the `binaryInterval` function do? It is defined but never called.

Comment: Please be more clear as to what interval is to be returned and in what format. Your example `60-70` does not seem to make sense in your example `sequence`. Or is my partial understanding completely off?

Comment: Do you mean that it should locate values that are in that interval, in this case `69`?

Comment: Yeah I am trying to change the binaryInterval function so that it will locate the value in the interval so yeah for example 69

Comment: I have edited what I had wrote hope it is easier to understand

Comment: Unless you are doing this as a learning exercise you could save yourself some time by using **bisect**, which is built in to Python. Documentation is available in section 8.6 of the 3.4 help document.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is pretty simple:
While searching for the elements in the interval `(lower, upper)`, perform a binary search on the array `arr` for the index of the smallest element `arr[n]`, such that `arr[n] >= lower` and the index of the largest element `arr[m]`, such that `arr[m] <= upper`.

Now there are several possibilities:

- n < m: there exist multiple solutions in the array. All of the are in the subarray starting at index `n` up to index `m` inclusively
- n = m: there exists precisely one solution: `arr[n]`
- n > m: no solutions exist

Searching for values beyond a certain threshold can be done using binary search like this:

```
def lowestGreaterThan(arr, threshold):
    low = 0
    high = len(arr)

    while low < high:
        mid = math.floor((low + high) / 2)

        print("low = ", low, " mid = ", mid, " high = ", high)

        if arr[mid] == threshold:
            return mid
        elif arr[mid] < threshold and mid != low:
            low = mid
        elif arr[mid] > threshold and mid != high:
            high = mid
        else:
            # terminate with index pointing to the first element greater than low
            high = low = low + 1

    return low
```

Sorry bout the looks of the code, my python is far from perfect. Anyways, this ought to show the basic idea behind the approach. The algorithm basically searches for the index `ind` of the first element in the array with the property `arr[ind] >= threshold`.

Comment: Hi I understand what you are saying with the lower and upper however Im unaware of how to apply this (sorry I'm getting into coding at school at just trying to learn)

Comment: @PeterMikel Well, binary search can not only be applied to search for a specific value in an array, but also for values that are beyond a certain threshold. I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: @PeterMikel Glad to help you :) since you seem to be new here: it's common use here, to mark an answer as accepted, if it solves your problem. [This article](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) describes how to do that ;)